# Next/Prev Arrows on a 1pg. horiz sliding website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've seen many similar question to this one but none of them seem to help on this particular code that i am using.  I definately need a PROs help here if anyone thinks they can be of assistance.  It would be greatly appreciated...

I have a simple horizontal sliding website.  The links at the top of the page work fine and scroll to the correct page.  However, what I am trying to do is add a Next and Previous arrow over the page in order to allow people to scroll from page to page in succession using those as well.  But that's where all the nasty begins.

I have posted some of my code here but to make this easier on anyone helping, you can view the entire thing (in genereic form) here... http://jsfiddle.net/Versitek/uZ2h8/17/

I suspect that the problem most likely lies in the arrow code...

```
<div id="prev-arrow"><a href="javascript: $('#banner a').trigger('click');"><FONT size="7"><STRONG>&laquo;</STRONG></FONT></a></div>

<div id="next-arrow"><a href="javascript: $('#banner a').trigger('click');"><FONT size="7"><STRONG>&raquo;</STRONG></FONT></a></div>
```

...or the javascript that is supposed to be controlling it...

```
$(function () {
    $("#banner").cycle({
        fx: 'fade',
        width: '100%',
        fit: 1,
        prevNextEvent: 'click.cycle',
        speed: 800,
        timeout: 10000,
        prev: '#prev-arrow',
        next: '#next-arrow',
        cleartypeNoBg: true
    });
});
```

Please try not too laugh too hard when looking at my code.  It's painfully OBVIOUS that I have no idea what I am doing here.  I'm hoping that it's simply something small that i am overlooking but there is a very good chance that I'm just an idiot.  PLEASE help.

Comment: U mean only next prev dont work correct?

Comment: Your fiddle is calling a jQuery plugin called .cycle() that isn't actually included, so we can't help much yet.

Comment: yes the arrows are not working.  It just scrolls to the last item every time.

Comment: I'm using the code provided here on this example page ... http://s3.sitepoint.com/examples/sidescroll/demo3.html

I'm trying to add nav arrows to that.

Comment: no help?  certainly someone must have an alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

things I did to get your cycle project working:

1. stripped the menu for easy working since you already know how to do that.
2. added the cycle plugin file to the fiddle
3. wrote a 'panels' container around the panel elements
4. called the cycle function with the 'panels' container.
5. changed the css a bit since I removed the menu

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joopmicroop/wLdFy/2/)

```
.
```

Comment: ok, I already got this working prior to your answer but since you showed a working solution, I'll check this one as the best answer.  Thanks.  I can use that working code in the future for other projects as well.